# classpath configurations.runtimeClasspath and rootSpec.Include

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am trying to generate multiple war file in same Project. one is main war and subPrj war where i tried add all dependencies from main war to subPrj war. I am trying to achieve it via following code.

```
task prjEmail(type: War) {
            
            rootSpec.exclude("**/applicationContext.xml")
            rootSpec.rename ('applicationContext-prj-jobs.xml','applicationContext.xml')
           // duplicatesStrategy=DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
          // classpath configurations.runtimeClasspath
            rootSpec.include("**/domain/**"
                
            )
            extension = 'job'
            
       }
    }
```

here Problem is when I use Classpath configurations.runtimeClasspath I am able to add all dependencies from main war to child but it also brings all classes which i dont want. I would like to add specific classes which I am trying to do with rootSpec.include but seems rootSpec.include and classpath configurations dont work together..
could you please suggest how to do it.
Jordan